# Heap Memory Size Increases While Adding Bitmaps in Arraylists in Android?

Tags: android

I am making a painting application in which I have to add bitmaps of images in an Arraylist when drawing many lines. Unfortunately, I got an out of memory exception. I am unable to fix the issue, though I have increased the size of heap.

I am adding current bitmaps in an Arraylist like this:

```
linesbitmap.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap));
```

Answer (score 4):

> Heap memory size is increases while adding bitmaps in arraylits in Android?

Of course. If you pour more water into a bucket, the bucket will contain more water. If you put more stuff in a bag, the bag will contain more stuff. If you allocate more memory, you will be using more memory. This has nothing much to do with Android -- this is the way computers have worked for the past ~50 years.

> i am unable to handle it

Use less memory:

- Have fewer bitmaps in the list
- Have smaller bitmaps (fewer pixels, lower color depth) in the list
- Remove and `recycle()` bitmaps in the list before adding more to the list
- Move data out of memory and into files (e.g., persist your bitmaps, then remove them from the list)
- Save data more efficiently (e.g., retain instructions on how to draw a line, instead of a bitmap representing the line)
- And so on

> i have also increase the size of heap

You cannot increase the size of the heap on most versions of Android.